# Android architecture for background services app consumed by several activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing an application in Android.
Once it starts I create a background service which extends IntentService and implements     SensorEventListener.
That class is responsible for listening to location updates and sensor updates like those coming from the acceletometer.

Then I create the main window and it checks for example wheather the GPS is enabled or not and some other stuff. If everything is correct, the from the main Activity I start another one.
I create it like this:

```
Intent startDrIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(startDrIntent);
```

Now I want in the DrActivity to show the coordinates and accelerometer values.

What's the best approach to get those values shown in the Activity?
I can think of this two:

1) Somehow have a handler of the activity in the application and from the sensing service class on each sensor or location update use app handler (static maybe?) and change the values of the TextView(s)

2) In the application have public static values of the coordinates and sensor and then consume that from the Activity (the problem here is how to let the Activity know that there was an update.

3) Anything better?

I cannot use AsyncTask as the background services will be consumed by several activities, not just one.
Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Comment: Why don't you have a singleton object that is the sensor listener, in which the activities register to listen for events. Each time an event arrives it passes to the activities listening.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have DrActivity implement SensorEventListener as well?

```
public class DrActivity implements SensorEventListener
{
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg0.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT)
        {
             textLightSensorData.setText("Light Sensor Date:"
           + String.valueOf(arg0.values[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this should probably be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: The sensors background service is run and consumed by several Activities as said in the title, so if I'd do that the rest of the Activities will be unable to consume sensor data

Comment: Any Activity which implements SensorEventListener could consumer sensor data, no? You could even create a BaseSensorActivity which implements SensorEventListener and then have all Activities which need to get sensor events extend from BaseSensorActivity.

Comment: The sensor service is independent of the Activities plus I have another Location service which is consumed by the activities as well. If I create a base class which extends SensorEventListener then (correct me if I'm wrong) but I'll one service initialization per Activity. I know I can make it static and have only one instance. But I don't see it as a good architecture.

Comment: I'm not suggesting starting a new service in BaseSensorActivity. I'm suggesting letting BaseSensorActivity implement SensorEventListener and then extending BaseSensorActivity for every Activity you'd like to get sensor data in.

Comment: Hi Karim, sorry in my delay to answer. Now I get what you're saying and sounds pretty logical, but what I've done it's DrActivity implement SensorEventListener but creating a breakpoint in public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event), doesn't seem to be hit. I don't need to register again the sensors here right? implementing the interface should be enough to have the breakpoint be hit?

Thanks! Guillermo.

Comment: Hey Guillermo, yes you'd need to register each Activity as a listener. There's a good example here:
http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.com/2011/12/shake-listener-demoexample.html

Comment: Hi Karim, sorry in my delay to reply, but I was testing something. What I don't get quite well is, if I register another listener in the Activity, Will I need to unregister later each one of the listeners, or there is a way to unregister all of them at once?

Comment: Hey Guillermo, have you figured this out yet? I'm not really sure what you're asking here. You should register the Activity AS THE listener. Do you have a need to unregister Activities as listeners?